# Question regarding changing from natural log to e

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$-\ln\left| 150 - y\right|=\frac{t}{200}-\ln130$$
$$\left| 150 - y\right|=130e^{-t/200}$$

I got $-130e^{t/200}$

Why is $e$ positive and the fraction negative?

Comment: Start by multiplying the entire equation by -1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From
$$
-\ln\left| 150 - y\right|=\frac{t}{200}-\ln130
$$ you have, *by multiplying by* $-1$, 
$$
\ln\left| 150 - y\right|=\ln130-\frac{t}{200}
$$ giving by exponentiation
$$
\left| 150 - y\right|=e^{\large \ln130-\frac{t}{200}}=e^{\ln130}\cdot e^{\large -\frac{t}{200}}=130\cdot e^{\large -\frac{t}{200}}
$$ as given.

Answer (score 0):

it is $$\ln\left(\frac{130}{|150-y|}\right)=e^{t/200}$$ and then by multiplication with $$e^{-t/200}$$ we get
$$130\cdot e^{-t/200}=|150-y|$$